# Make [google-console-developer] a synonym for [google-cloud-console]

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

I just ran across another strange tag [google-console-developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-console-developer)

I believe this is meant to be

- [google-cloud-console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-console) [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)

Which should not be confused with

- [google-developer-console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-developer-console) [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/)

I tried to create a synonym but its returning an error:

> Creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag.